# Using a SAS format catalogue

Tags: sas, data-formats

I received a dataset and a format catalogue in SAS, and I am trying to get it to open, but somehow I am not correctly applying the format catalogue.  Here is the code I've used.  I have researched SAS sites and I thought I had the correct steps to call in the catalogue, but it's not working.  I'm sure it's a basic error I'm making.

```
libname in 'U:/';
libname library 'U:/';

Options fmtsearch = (library.formats_raw); 

data ae;
set in.ae;
format 
    aeactae $AEMGMT.
    AEACTSM $ACTION.
    AEDVIS $VISIT.
    AEENDT DATE11.
    AEINT $AEINT.
    AEIRLOC $INJSITE.
    AEIRMEAS $YESNO.
    AEIRTERM $ISR.
    AEIRVIS $VISIT.
    AEIRYN $YESNO.
    AEOUT $OUTCOME.
    aerel $aerel.
    AESER $YESNO.
    AESTDT DATE11.
    AEYN $YESNO.
    EVTDT DATE11.
    LASTUPD EURDFDT20.;
run;
```

For each variable, I get the following error in the log:

```
format
            aeactae $AEMGMT.
                     --------               
ERROR 48-59: The format $AEMGMT was not found or could not be loaded.
```

Comment: What's the precise filename for the format catalog?

Comment: U:/formats_raw.sas7bdat

Comment: Ah, then you don't have a format catalog!

Comment: I apologize...  was sent the sas7bdat file, and then by running a proc, it converted it to formats_raw.sas7bcat which I think is the catalogue file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Given the new information the answer changes.  I leave the rest in case it's useful.

You have a format dataset, not a format catalog.  You need to run this:

```
proc format cntlin=in.formats_raw;
quit;
```

to import the formats.  This assumes it's created properly of course - it should have, at least, `fmtname`, `start`, `label`, and probably some other variables also (`type`, `hlo`, `end` are common).

This imports formats saved to a `SAS` dataset to the work environment.  If you want to create a permanent catalog, you should specify `lib=in` or wherever you want them stored on the `proc format` statement.

---

Old answer:

You're generally doing it right, though you're doing some things in ways you don't need to.

`library` libname should be avoided.  It's something people use who don't know how to use formats properly, but it really is not a good idea, because it gets special preference in format searching in a way that can be problematic if you have more than one. `LIBRARY` and `WORK` are automatically in the fmtsearch list and are given first priority unless explicitly listed. But that doesn't actually help you when the format catalog is not `formats.sas7bcat` anyway.

In your case you should just define it once (`in`) and then do this:

```
libname in 'U:/';
Options fmtsearch = (in.formats_raw work);
```

You put `work` in there to make sure your format catalog gets priority over it.

Then it should work, if you have a file `formats_raw.sas7bcat` in that folder.  If you don't, then you may have something else going on (you may have a file that's intended to be imported through `cntlin` if it is a `.sas7bdat` for example).

This is a simple example of this working:

```
libname temp 'c:\temp';
proc format lib=temp.formats_raw;
  value YNF
  1='Yes'
  2='No'
  ;
quit;

options fmtsearch=(temp.formats_raw work);

data test;
  x=1;
  format x YNF.;
  put x= ynf.;
run;
```

Change the `fmtsearch` to `(temp work)` and you'll see it fail (since `temp\formats.sas7bcat` does not exist).

Comment: Thank you - the problem was I had not run this statement: 'proc format cntlin=in.formats_raw;
quit;'